# How to add group choices in the Object Permissions form of the admin interface with django-guardian?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-guardian

Using `guardian` in a `django` project, I want the admins to be able to assign object permissions over the admin interface. With `guardian` this is possible, but the *Object permissions* form in the admin interface, the *Group* field is a `TextField`. How do I make it a `ChoiceField` with all existing groups as choices?

Is there a solution that only requires adding code in the `admin.py` file of the app or do we have to overwrite some `guardian` code? How can we do it without messing with the functionality of `guardian`?
This is my `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin

class MyModelAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that works like a charm.
First subclass the GuardedModelAdminMixin

```
from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin, GuardedModelAdminMixin

class CustomGuardedModelAdminMixin(GuardedModelAdminMixin):
    def get_obj_perms_group_select_form(self, request):
        """
        Returns form class for selecting a group for permissions management.  By default :form:`GroupManage` is
        returned. This enhancement returns GroupModelManage instead, allowing admins to get a queryset of groups.
        """
        return GroupModelManage
```

Then define the ModelManager for groups with overriding the clean_group function:

```
class GroupModelManage(forms.Form):
    """
    Extends the Django Guardian GroupManage class to select User from a query containing all
    User objects rather than a blank input CharField.
    """
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

    def clean_group(self):
        """
        Returns ``Group`` instance based on the given group name.
        """
        try:
            return self.cleaned_data['group']
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.fields['group'].error_messages['does_not_exist'])
```

Finally, use the new Mixin in your Admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(CustomGuardedModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

To do custom querysets on the user level, use this function in the new mixin:

```
    def get_obj_perms_user_select_form(self, request):
        return UserModelManage
```

A full example is here: [LINK](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet/issues/268#issuecomment-459125970)